# jQuery disable the last checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, click

Have a look at parts of my script.

It is for a series of checkboxes that i populate from a PHP script. The rendered`HTML` looks something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='3' id='checkbox-id-3' name='selectCityCheckbox[]' checked><label for='checkbox-id-3'>Description</label>
<input type='checkbox' value='5' id='checkbox-id-5' name='selectCityCheckbox[]' checked><label for='checkbox-id-5'>Description</label>
<input type='checkbox' value='7' id='checkbox-id-5' name='selectCityCheckbox[]'><label for='checkbox-id-7'>Description</label>
```

What I need now is a function to disable the last available checkbox and make it unclickable. The function should be called on every click and on DOM load.

Some jQuery:

```
var $eye = $('#eye');
var $eyeDropdown = $('#eyeDropdown');
var $checkboxes = $eyeDropdown.find(':checkbox');
var $eyeCheckedBoxes = $('#eyeDropdown :checkbox:checked');

$checkboxes.on('click', update);
function update() {
    $wrapper.html($img);
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var value = checkbox.val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var viewOnlineValue = 1;
    } else {
        $(this).is(':checked');
        var viewOnlineValue = 0;
    }
    $.ajax({
        /*ajax stuff*/

    });
    lockLastCheckbox();        
}
```

I'm working on a function now, but it doesn't seem to register the changes of `$(this).is(':checked');` from the `update()` function, thus not adding or removing anything from the variable `sumChecked`

```
function lockLastCheckbox() {
    var sumChecked = $eyeCheckedBoxes.length;
    console.log(sumChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to `check` your `checkbox` in else part like,

```
var viewOnlineValue;
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    viewOnlineValue = 1;
} else {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    viewOnlineValue = 0;
}
```

**Alternative**,

```
....
else {
    this.checked=true;
    viewOnlineValue = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that but it makes no difference on the variable `sumChecked`

Comment: You need to pass checkbox object in `update()` function. and remove `this`

Answer (score 0):

i thing you should have to use.

```
$('input:checkbox:last').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This will disable the last rendered checkbox. Not really helping me. Maybe I was unclear in my question but I want the last available checkbox to be disabled, i.e. the only one with value `checked`

Comment: i thing you find on http://jsfiddle.net/PZjT6/ here last checkbox disable with jquery.